# Left action of a group acting on a function in Polya Counting

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a group $G\leq S_{n}$ where $X$ is a ﬁnite set of cardinality $|X| = n $. Let $C = \{{c1,c2,...,cm}\}$; where we call the elements of C colours. We consider $f ∈ C^{X}$, that is a function $f : X → C $.

This being the only information we have, I'm struggling to understand why the following is true:

$(g·f )(x) = (f ◦g^{−1})(x) = f (g^{-1}(x))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equality is the definition of the action of $G$ on $C^X$.  The second equality is the definition of $\circ$.